# C++ - Overload operator > and pointers

Tags: c++, class, pointers, overloading

I'm building a C++ project about rational numbers.
I've already defined a class, named RationalNumber, with constructors and overloading of arithmetical (+, -, *, /), relational (<, >, <=, >=) and equality (==, !=) operators, but also >>. I've two private attributes: numerator and denominator (integers).
Now, I've a question! It's possible to re-overload operator > in order to return a pointer at bigger of two RationalNumber objects? If yes, how could I do?

I tried in this way:

```
RationalNumber* RationalNumber::operator>(const RationalNumber& rn){
 RationalNumber bigger;
 if((double(numerator)/double(denominator) > double(rn.numerator)/double(rn.denominator))){
    bigger.set_numerator(numerator);
    bigger.set_denominator(denominator);
 }
 else{
    bigger.set_numerator(rn.numerator);
    bigger.set_denominator(rn.denominator);
 }
 return &bigger;
}
```

where

```
void set_numerator   (int num)   { numerator=num; }
void set_denominator (int denom) { denominator=denom; }
```

and setting numerator and denominator as public attributes.
In *main* function I tried to print

```
RationalNumber a( 2, 3 ), b( 1, 3 );
cout<<(a>b);
```

but I'm not sure it's the correct way!
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: `return &bigger;` would return dangling pointer.

Comment: Madness! What next, overloading `<<` and `>>` to read and write rational numbers??

Comment: `std::cout << std::max(a, b);`?

Comment: *"Is it possible to re-overload `operator >`"* You cannot have (not template) function/method which differ only by their return type.

Comment: Real question is why return  type of `operator>` should be different then `bool`? Does somone tries screw up readers of code?

Comment: This must be professor of something unrelated to coding. Note this design of API may lead to this kind of code: `(a > b)->set_numerator(3)` or `*(a > b)` which is totally confusing.

Comment: *return a pointer at bigger of two RationalNumber objects?* -- Your professor, sorry to say, wasted a big part, if not a whole day on this, when there are much more relevant C++ issues that could have been taught.

Answer (score -1):

> It's possible to re-overload operator > in order to return a pointer
> at bigger of two RationalNumber objects? If yes, how could I do?

Yes it is possible, but it would be better to return a reference not a pointer:

```cpp
const RationalNumber& operator>(const RationalNumber& a, const RationalNumber& b)
{
    return a.greaterThen(b) ? a : b;
}
```

This will return reference (which can be converted to pointer) to greater number, but this is as good idea as sticking your finger into a wall socket. Possible, but not wise. Side note: I used `greaterThen` method to avoid reusing your code which I dislike (this is another topic).

Note that your type is an arithmetic type. It should behave like other arithmetic types: `int`, `double` .... . So anyone who will use `RationalNumber` could quickly understand how to write and read code using this type.

So it is expected that this compiles and works in standard way, for example:

```cpp
if (a > b) { // with your overload will not compile or will lead to unexpected behavior
   ...
}

if (a > b && b > c) { // same as above
   ...
}

// note this overloads:
foo(RationalNumber x);
foo(bool codition);

foo(a > b); // now unexpected function is called
```